# Django Validators.py

Tags: django

please your help.
I have the next code:

**form.py**

```
from .validators import MaxSizeFileValidator

    class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):  
        name = forms.CharField(min_length=5, max_length=50)
        image = forms.ImageField(required=False, validators=[MaxSizeFileValidator(max_file_size=2)])
```

**validator.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
class MaxSizeFileValidator:
    def __init__(self, max_file_size=5):
        self.max_file_size = max_file_size
    def __class__(self,value):
        size = value.size
        max_size = self.max_file_size * 1048576
        if size > max_size:
            raise ValidationError(f"Not permitted size image, must be: {self.max_file_size}MB")
        return value
```

When a run the code, the page show the next:

```
TypeError at /add-product/
'MaxSizeFileValidator' object is not callable
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/add-product/
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'MaxSizeFileValidator' object is not callable
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A validator is supposed to be callable. It appears you attempted to do that but the method you need to implement is `__call__` yet you name it as `__class__` (might cause other errors also), simply change that method to be named `__call__`, also no need to return anything from a validator:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class MaxSizeFileValidator:
    def __init__(self, max_file_size=5):
        self.max_file_size = max_file_size
    
    def __call__(self, value):
        size = value.size
        max_size = self.max_file_size * 1048576
        if size > max_size:
            raise ValidationError(f"Not permitted size image, must be: {self.max_file_size}MB")
        # No need to return here
```